# AngularJS binding template variable

Tags: angularjs

I have to renderize the template dynamically depending the layout sended (for now we have original and alternative).

In the beggining I was traking manually in the html. Like this:

```
<component layout="original"></component>
```

Component template:

```
template: ($element, $attrs) => {
    let process = 'original';
    if ($attrs.layout) {
      process = $attrs.layout;
    }
    return require(`./templates/${process}.html`);
  }
```

But now I have to compile according the variable. For example:

```
<component layout="{{vm.templateType}}"></component>
```

But when I acess the `$attrs` in the `template` the Angular is not compiled and the result is the string like this:`"{{vm.templateType}}"`.

There is a way to force the template compilation before run the template function?

Comment: Have you tried [ngSwitch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch)?

Comment: don't use `{{ }}` in the HTML, `layout="vm.templateType"` should give you the value you need.

Comment: No, I'm not able to acess it. I'm trying to access it from the template to return the correct template and I don't have acess to this "variables"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem in AngularJS you can check the discuss here: [#2895](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2895) and [#13526](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/13526).

To solve it I had to use the `$compile` in the controller like this:

```
this.$onChanges = function (obj) {
  const layout = require(`./templates/${obj.layout.currentValue}.html`);
  $element.append($compile(layout)($scope));
};
```

And remove the template attr of the component.